# "refers to a value, but is being used as a type here." Facebook import

Tags: angular, facebook, ionic-framework, typeof

So I was adding Facebook login into my app and I was following the documentation for Ionic v4,

https://ionicframework.com/docs/v4/native/facebook/

and I was getting an error when adding the `Facebook` item from the import in the constructor parameters.

```
import { Facebook, FacebookLoginResponse } from '@ionic-native/facebook/ngx';

constructor(private fb: Facebook) { }
```

`private fb: Facebook` is throwing a `'Facebook' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof Facebook'?` error.

I'm sure it's just a syntax error, but I don't know the proper syntax.

Comment: is your constructor method inside class object or goes right after imports? can you share more code that you have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of TypeScript 3.8 it is possible to use [Type-Only Imports](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-8.html).
To make sure the imported parameter is not a value, but a type do this:

```ts
import type { Facebook } from '@ionic-native/facebook/ngx';
```